Will additional pension contributions reduce a self assessment tax bill?
I am employed (PAYE) and make pension contributions through salary sacrifice.
I earned more than expected last year and had to complete a self assessment which has resulted in a tax bill of a few thousand £.
Is it possible to make some additional pension contributions to lower this bill? If so, would I have to wait until next year’s self assessment or could I claim this tax relief before 31st January when the tax payment is due?

You can’t reduce last year’s tax bill by reducing this year’s taxable income, but your tax payment due in January will largely be a payment on account for the first half of the current tax year, and you can apply to reduce that payment on account citing increased pension contributions as the reason. Such an application will normally be accepted, unless you have a history of making such applications that eventually turned out to be unjustified.

Most people whose primary/only income is through employment won't be making payments on account - the requirement only arises if your self assessment bill is miles away from what was deducted through PAYE.

@GaneshSittampalam But he says he has a tax bill of several thousand pounds, which suggests that his PAYE deduction was miles away from what he actually owed.

https://www.gov.uk/understand-self-assessment-bill/payments-on-account - most people in this situation will hit the 80% threshold comfortably. The OP didn't say exactly why they ended up with the tax bill but the most common scenario with unexpectedly high earnings is going over £100K and getting hit with personal allowance withdrawal - in which case you are likely paying £30K through PAYE already.
